# Include issue: 'multiple definition', 'first defined here'

Tags: c++

I have three files:

```
main.cpp
MyClass.cpp
MyClass.hpp
```

I have a library header file, `"testLib.hpp"`, that I want to include in `MyClass.hpp` so that I can have one of testLib's objects be a class attribute.

I include `MyClass.hpp` in `MyClass.cpp` and in `main.cpp`. When attempting to compile the project, I get the following errors

```
MyClass.cpp   multiple definition of 'testLib::testLib::function1()
obj/Release/main.o:main.cpp first defined here
MyClass.cpp   multiple definition of 'testLib::testLib::function2()
obj/Release/main.o:main.cpp first defined here
```

and so on.

Both `main.cpp` and `MyClass.cpp` include `MyClass.hpp` (which includes `testLib.hpp`). Judging by the error, it looks like `MyClass.cpp` is attempting to include the library functions after they've already been included by `main.cpp`. However, I have include guards present in `MyClass.hpp` so I don't understand how it's trying to include `MyClass.hpp` twice.

Here's the code:

MyClass.hpp

```
#ifndef THIS_HEADER_H
#define THIS_HEADER_H

#include <stdint.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "testLib/testLib.hpp"

class MyClass
{

public:
    void test();
    int foo;

private:
    uint32_t bar;
    //I want to include an object from the library as part of this class
    //TestLib::Device device;
};

#endif
```

MyClass.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "MyClass.hpp"

void MyClass::test()
{

}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "MyClass.hpp"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT**
I tried to hide the actual filenames to make the question more general and clear, but it seems like the problem might be resulting from 'testLib.hpp', which I did not write. That file is actually the following "sweep.hpp" file. I got the 'multiple definition of/first defined here' errors for each of the public functions in this file:

sweep.hpp

```
#ifndef SWEEP_DC649F4E94D3_HPP
#define SWEEP_DC649F4E94D3_HPP

/*
 * C++ Wrapper around the low-level primitives.
 * Automatically handles resource management.
 *
 * sweep::sweep  - device to interact with
 * sweep::scan   - a full scan returned by the device
 * sweep::sample - a single sample in a full scan
 *
 * On error sweep::device_error gets thrown.
 */

#include <cstdint>
#include <memory>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <vector>

#include <sweep/sweep.h>

namespace sweep {

// Error reporting

struct device_error final : std::runtime_error {
  using base = std::runtime_error;
  using base::base;
};

// Interface

struct sample {
  const std::int32_t angle;
  const std::int32_t distance;
  const std::int32_t signal_strength;
};

struct scan {
  std::vector<sample> samples;
};

class sweep {
public:
  sweep(const char* port);
  sweep(const char* port, std::int32_t bitrate);
  void start_scanning();
  void stop_scanning();
  bool get_motor_ready();
  std::int32_t get_motor_speed();
  void set_motor_speed(std::int32_t speed);
  std::int32_t get_sample_rate();
  void set_sample_rate(std::int32_t speed);
  scan get_scan();
  void reset();

private:
  std::unique_ptr<::sweep_device, decltype(&::sweep_device_destruct)> device;
};

// Implementation

namespace detail {
struct error_to_exception {
  operator ::sweep_error_s*() { return &error; }

  ~error_to_exception() noexcept(false) {
    if (error) {
      device_error e{::sweep_error_message(error)};
      ::sweep_error_destruct(error);
      throw e;
    }
  }

  ::sweep_error_s error = nullptr;
};
}

sweep::sweep(const char* port)
    : device{::sweep_device_construct_simple(port, detail::error_to_exception{}), &::sweep_device_destruct} {}

sweep::sweep(const char* port, std::int32_t bitrate)
    : device{::sweep_device_construct(port, bitrate, detail::error_to_exception{}), &::sweep_device_destruct} {}

void sweep::start_scanning() { ::sweep_device_start_scanning(device.get(), detail::error_to_exception{}); }

void sweep::stop_scanning() { ::sweep_device_stop_scanning(device.get(), detail::error_to_exception{}); }

bool sweep::get_motor_ready() { return ::sweep_device_get_motor_ready(device.get(), detail::error_to_exception{}); }

std::int32_t sweep::get_motor_speed() { return ::sweep_device_get_motor_speed(device.get(), detail::error_to_exception{}); }

void sweep::set_motor_speed(std::int32_t speed) {
  ::sweep_device_set_motor_speed(device.get(), speed, detail::error_to_exception{});
}

std::int32_t sweep::get_sample_rate() { return ::sweep_device_get_sample_rate(device.get(), detail::error_to_exception{}); }

void sweep::set_sample_rate(std::int32_t rate) {
  ::sweep_device_set_sample_rate(device.get(), rate, detail::error_to_exception{});
}

scan sweep::get_scan() {
  using scan_owner = std::unique_ptr<::sweep_scan, decltype(&::sweep_scan_destruct)>;

  scan_owner releasing_scan{::sweep_device_get_scan(device.get(), detail::error_to_exception{}), &::sweep_scan_destruct};

  auto num_samples = ::sweep_scan_get_number_of_samples(releasing_scan.get());

  scan result;
  result.samples.reserve(num_samples);

  for (std::int32_t n = 0; n < num_samples; ++n) {
    auto angle = ::sweep_scan_get_angle(releasing_scan.get(), n);
    auto distance = ::sweep_scan_get_distance(releasing_scan.get(), n);
    auto signal = ::sweep_scan_get_signal_strength(releasing_scan.get(), n);

    result.samples.push_back(sample{angle, distance, signal});
  }

  return result;
}

void sweep::reset() { ::sweep_device_reset(device.get(), detail::error_to_exception{}); }

} // ns

#endif
```

Comment: Did you try  #pragma once

Comment: Include guards prevent the same header from being included twice into the same source. They don't prevent the same header being included into multiple sources (nor should they; that's precisely the intended usage of headers). The primary sin is that `testLib.hpp` header defines a couple of functions. A header should only declare the functions (which should be defined in some source file); or else define them with `inline` keyword.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Thanks for the response. I included the actual library file (sweep.hpp) that I named 'testLib.hpp' in the original post. I did not write sweep.hpp. It looks like they did declare some of the functions that I got errors. So you're saying the error completely comes from sweep.hpp?

Comment: All the function bodies in sweep.hpp are a mistake and should not be there. You might be able to work around by changing them all to be `inline`

Comment: Please don't modify errors, post the _actual_ messages reported by the compiler.

Comment: @P0W Sorry, tried to make the question more general but I agree that I should have just included the original source code from the beginning.

Comment: Looking at the latest GitHub repo for the library, it looks like they indeed did change all the functions to be inline

Comment: Just move everything below `// Implementation` in sweep.hpp to sweep.cpp. That is the place for the implementations and this way you will not violated *ODR*

Answer (score 30, accepted):

A simplified version of your problem:

buggy.hpp

```
int function() { return 0; }
```

main.cpp

```
 #include "buggy.hpp"
 int main() { return 0; }
```

other.cpp

```
 #include "buggy.hpp"
```

The problem is that `buggy.hpp` is *defining* `function`, not just *declaring*.  Once the header inclusion is expanded, that means `function` is declared in both `main.cpp` and `other.cpp` - and that is not allowed.

The fix is to declare `function` as `inline` which allows the function to be declared in multiple translation units.

```
inline int function() { return 0; }
```

In fact, allowing multiple definitions is the *only* meaning of `inline` to the C++ *standard*.  Compilers may treat it as a hint that the function body may be expanded inline.  Good ones won't; they are better at making that sort of decision that programmers).

Comment: Thank you so much! You saved my day. :)

Comment: It's weird. I can define classes in my .hpp file, including methods on them, without triggering this problem. But not free functions. Why the inconsistency?

Comment: @interstar 1.  You can have (and actually need) types (including classes) to be defined in each translation unit they are used.  2.  If you put `struct foo { int bar(); }; int foo::bar() { return 0; }` in you header file, you will have exactly the same problem.  The difference is that if you define a member function *in* a class definition, it is implicitly declared `inline`.

Comment: That also saved my day, great answer!